# Exclude posts from loop by term

Tags: loop, terms

Here is how the loop looks? I need to exclude a few posts with the custom term, how can I manage it

```
<?php
    global $post, $PIXAD_Autos;
    $Settings = new PIXAD_Settings();
    $settings = $Settings->getSettings( 'WP_OPTIONS', '_pixad_autos_settings', true );

    $validate = $Settings->getSettings( 'WP_OPTIONS', '_pixad_autos_validation', true ); // Get validation settings

    $showInSidebar = pixad::getsideviewfields($validate);
    $validate = pixad::validation( $validate ); // Fix undefined index notice

    $auto_translate = unserialize( get_option( '_pixad_auto_translate' ) );


    ?>

    <div class="row">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php 
                $comment_args = array( 'status' => 'approve', 'post_id' => $post->ID, );
                $comments = get_comments($comment_args);
                $post_rating = [];
                foreach($comments as $comment){
                    $post_rating[] = floatval( get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true ) );
                }
                ?>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                               <div class="slider-grid__inner slider-grid__inner_mod-b">

                                    <div class="card__img">
                       <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
                         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('autozone_latest_item', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
                        </a>


                    <?php else: ?>
                        <img class="no-image" src="<?php echo PIXAD_AUTO_URI .'assets/img/no_image.jpg'; ?>" alt="no-image">
                    <?php endif; ?>


                    <?php if( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pixad_auto_featured_text', true) ): ?>
                        <span class="card__wrap-label"><span class="card__label"><?php echo  get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'pixad_auto_featured_text', true ); ?></span></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>


                    <?php if( $validate['auto-price_show'] && $PIXAD_Autos->get_meta('_auto_price') ): ?>
                   <span class="slider-grid__price_wrap"><span class="slider-grid__price"><span><?php echo wp_kses_post($PIXAD_Autos->get_price()); ?></span></span></span> 
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php do_action( 'autozone_autos_single_auto_img', $post ); ?>
                </div>
                         <div class="tmpl-gray-footer">
                            <span class="tmpl-slider-grid__name"><?php echo wp_kses_post(get_the_title())?></span>
                        <?php if(!empty($post_rating)):?>
                            <div class="star-rating"><span style="width:<?php echo  esc_html( array_sum($post_rating)/count($post_rating) * 20 );?>%"></span></div>
                        <?php endif;?>      

                        <ul class="tmpl-slider-grid__info list-unstyled">

                                 <?php foreach ($showInSidebar as $id => $sideAttribute):?>
                                      <?php   $id='_'.$id; 
                                     $id = str_replace('-', '_', $id); 
                                      ?>
                                     <?php  if( $PIXAD_Autos->get_meta($id) ): ?>
                                    <li><i class="<?php echo esc_html($sideAttribute['icon'])?>"></i>
                                        <?php
                                        $val_attr =  $PIXAD_Autos->get_meta($id);
                                        if(!empty($auto_translate[$val_attr])  ){
                                          echo esc_html($auto_translate[$val_attr]);
                                        }else{
                                          echo esc_html($PIXAD_Autos->get_meta($id));
                                        }
                                          ?>
                                    </li>
                                     <?php endif; ?>

                                 <?php endforeach;?>
                             </ul>
                            </div> 

                         </div>  
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you asking how to exclude posts that contain certain text?
(mod please move this to a comment, I do not have the reputation)

Comment: Hi, my custom post type has a taxonomy, can I exclude posts with certain taxonomy id?

Comment: @george oh I'm glad you got it.  Can you rate my answer useful so I can get enough reputation for comments?  I am getting close to being able to comment on posts that are not mine, lol

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty simple, sorry for bothering you)

```
if( has_term( 'taxonomy slug', 'taxonomy' ) ) { 
continue;
}
```